# How can I split a Text in blocks of 16 bytes every one?

Tags: matlab

I need  to split a Text in blocs, where the size of every bloc is 16, 
For example:

Text:

```
60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81 1f 35 2c 07 3b 61 08 d7 2d 98 10 a3 09 14 df f4 60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81 1f 35 2c 07 3b 61 08 d7 2d 98 10 a3 09 14 df f4
```

Result:

```
60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81
1f 35 2c 07 3b 61 08 d7 2d 98 10 a3 09 14 df f4
60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81
1f 35 2c 07 3b 61 08 d7 2d 98 10 a3 09 14 df f4
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: What format is your text in? Is this in a file? A cell array? A multi-dimensional character array?

Comment: @Suever, It is a file, Thanks in advance

Comment: And what do you want the output to be? A cell array? A multi-dimensional character array?

Comment: @Suever, In fact the format is not important in my case, all what I need is to put my hexadecimal text in my function parameter, then i must be able to split this text in blocs of 16  bytes, i will need those blocs to cipher for encryption. So the output it maybe a vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just read this in using `fread` and then reshape the data.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'r');
alldata = fread(fid, '*char');
data = reshape(alldata, 3*16, []).';
fclose(fid)
```

If you want something a little more robust, you could use `textscan`.

```
fid = fopen('filename.txt', 'r');
alldata = textscan(fid, '%s');
data = cell2mat(reshape(alldata{1}, 32, [])).';
fclose(fid)
```

If the spaces are important, you can use `strjoin` to maintain the spaces

```
tmp = reshape(alldata{1}, 16, []).';
tmp = arrayfun(@(x)strjoin(tmp(x,:)), 1:size(tmp, 1), 'uniformoutput', false);
data = cat(1, tmp{:})
```

Comment: thank you very much the last solution gives me the best result.

Comment: please, could you tell me how can I have data result in a vector? I couldn't mae the difference between the creation of an array and a vector?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user6594048 So you want a 2D character array?