# How could I have each result as a vector?

Tags: matlab

I think that I have always the same problem, vector, array and cell array, Thanks to this discussion, [How can I split a Text in blocks of 16 bytes every one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506723/how-can-i-split-a-text-in-blocks-of-16-bytes-every-one)    I could resolve my first problem. However I still need that each result in data must be e vector in order to encrypt it.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
alldata = textscan(fid, '%s');
tmp = reshape(alldata{1}, 16, []).';
tmp = arrayfun(@(x)strjoin(tmp(x,:)), 1:size(tmp, 1), 'uniformoutput', false)
key=hex2dec(key_hex).'
data= (cat(1, tmp{:}))

for i= 1:rows(data)
  Matrix(i, :)= hex_keys([data(i,1:15), data(i,16)])
  chiffrement (Matrix(i,:), key,1)
endfor

endfunction
```

My error is: error: Plaintext has to be a vector (not a cell array) with 16 elements. 
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

The file.txt contains  for example:

60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81 60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81 60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81

In fact, it is a big programm and succesion of function, All what i need is how to convert each line in this data result to a vector.

```
data =

60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81
60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81
60 3d eb 10 15 ca 71 be 2b 73 ae f0 85 7d 77 81
```

Comment: could you please add some data to the question? a small file.txt woud help a lot

Comment: i feel like we would need more information for helping you. please add ley_hex, and the function hex_keys and chiffrement. in which function did the error occur?

Comment: Please, see the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are over complicating the problem, my assumptions is you want to convert your data in `file.txt` into numbers (i.e. you used `hex2dec`), so let's do just that and leave Arrayfun out of the problem:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
alldata = textscan(fid, '%s');
tmp = reshape(alldata{1}, 16, []).'; % here we still parse 16 hex for every row using your function call
tmp = cellfun(@hex2dec,tmp,'un',0) % now we use cellfun to convert all your hex to numbers
Matrix = cell2mat(tmp)

Matrix =

96    61   235    16    21   202   113   190    43   115   174   240   133   125   119   129
96    61   235    16    21   202   113   190    43   115   174   240   133   125   119   129
96    61   235    16    21   202   113   190    43   115   174   240   133   125   119   129

whos Matrix

Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

Matrix      3x16              384  double
```

Now you can use your for loop to do whatever you want, it becomes regular indexing.